# build() is called but display not updated until hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an async stream which generates consecutive integers every second:

```dart
Stream<int> f() async* {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }
}
```

I have a state `List<Widget> l = [];` and want to append a `Card` to it every second by using the stream.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    f().listen((d) {
      setState(
          () => this.l.add(Card(child: ListTile(title: Text(d.toString())))));
    });
}
```

And here's the `build()` method:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print('build(): ${this.l.length}');
  return ListView(children: this.l);
}
```

When I run the program via `flutter run -d macos` (i.e. macOS desktop app), display isn't updated at all although `build()` is called and `this.l` is updated every second. The console output is

```
flutter: build(): 0
flutter: build(): 1
flutter: build(): 2
flutter: build(): 3
flutter: build(): 4
flutter: build(): 5
...
```

If I press <kbd>r</kbd> key to perform hot reload, display is updated.

Why?

### How to reproduce:

1. `flutter run -d macos` to start the application.
2. Even if `build()` is called every second, display remains fully black.

   [image]
3. If you press <kbd>r</kbd> key to perform hot reload, display is updated.

   [image]

### Full code here:

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3c753f7f4e07cfa87182f77c7f0e7c05)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(body: W()),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class W extends StatefulWidget {
  const W({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<W> createState() => _WState();
}

class _WState extends State<W> {
  List<Widget> l = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Stream<int> f() async* {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        yield i;
      }
    }

    f().listen((d) {
      setState(
          () => this.l.add(Card(child: ListTile(title: Text(d.toString())))));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build(): ${this.l.length}');
    return ListView(children: this.l);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `ListView(children: this.l)` to

- `ListView(children: List.of(this.l))`
- or `ListView.builder(itemCount: l.length, itemBuilder: (_, i) => l[i])`

It's because `ListView` widget. `ListView` likes a static widget, it receives only the beginning argument list `l` and does not update even you call setState.

### More Strict Explanation

[The official document of `ListView()` constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html) says

> *Like other widgets in the framework, this widget expects that the children list will not be mutated after it has been passed in here. See the documentation at [*SliverChildListDelegate.children*](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverChildListDelegate/children.html) for more details.*

and the embedded link says

> *Also, a `Widget` in Flutter is immutable, so directly modifying the children such as `someWidget.children.add(...)` or passing a reference of the original list value to the children parameter will result in incorrect behaviors. Whenever the children list is modified, a new list object should be provided.*

Answer (score 0):

Use builder instead

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: W()),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class W extends StatefulWidget {
  const W({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<W> createState() => _WState();
}

class _WState extends State<W> {
  StreamController<int> streamController;
  List<String> list = []; // change the string to any data object

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    streamController = StreamController<int>();

    Stream<int> f() async* {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        yield i;
      }
    }

    f().listen((d) {
      setState(() {
        list.add(d.toString());
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build(): $itemCount');
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: itemCount,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final listItem = list[index];
        return Card(
          key: Key('card_$index'),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(listItem),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't cache widgets. The preferred approach is to store the state - in this case the list of strings received. In build, you then create the widgets on the fly.

```
class _WState extends State<W> {
  final strings = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Stream<int> f() async* {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        yield i;
      }
    }

    f().listen((d) {
      setState(() {
        strings.add(d.toString());
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        children: strings
            .map<Widget>((s) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(s),
                ))
            .toList());
  }
}
```